# Rules for song titles

Tags: ponctuation

What are the rules about writing song or book title?  In English, we put them in quotes.  For example:

> Prokofiev's "Peter and the Wolf" is a fun way to introduce kids to the orchestra.

Quelles sont les règles concernant l'écriture des titres de chansons ou de livres ?  En anglais, on les mets entre guillemets.  Serait-ce :

> « Pierre et le Loup » de Prokofiev est une façon amusante d'initier les enfants à la musique d'orchestre.

Comment: “In English, we put them in quotes.” — Not necessarily. It is true that many people use quotes for both, but style guides like the _The Chicago Manual of Style_ recommend italics for book and movie titles, but quotes for poems and songs (for instance).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [L'écriture des titres](https://www.axl.cefan.ulaval.ca/monde/regles-2TITRES.htm)
>
> Les titres de volume, d'un de nom de journal, d'une œuvre artistique, y compris au cinéma, prennent l'italique, alors que les titres d'articles de journal ou d'une revue prennent les guillemets ouvrants et fermants.

- *Pierre et le Loup*, de Prokofiev, est une façon amusante d'initier les enfants à la musique d'orchestre.